# Código Haskell a Scala

Tags: lista, map, haskell

Estoy aprendiendo dos lenguajes, me dieron una función para convertir de Haskell a Scala, sin embargo no lo comprendo muy bien. El código es el siguiente:

```
foldl (\x y->x+y) 0 (map (\x->16*x) [1..10])
```

Entiendo que `(\x y->x+y)` suma dos dígitos, también entiendo que `(map (\x->16*x) [1..10])` multiplica los dígitos del 1 al 10 por 16. Sin embargo, no comprendo el cero y qué se produce al unir todo el código. Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dices, `map (\x->16*x) [1..10]` es un modo de multiplicar por 16 los elementos del rango, algo equivalente a `[16*x | x <- [1..10]]` que resulta `[16,32,48,64,80,96,112,128,144,160]`.

`foldl` es una función de *reducción*, en concreto *doblado por la izquierda*. Se aplica una función de izquierda a derecha hasta obtener un valor.

Su signatura sería:

```hs
foldl :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> [a] -> a
fold op acc xs = ...
```

En el caso que propones, la función `op` sería la suma de dos elementos `\x y -> x+y`. El `0` sería el valor inicial. La primera operación sería la suma del elemento inicial y el primer elemento: `0 + 16 = 16`. Con este resultado, se vuelve a sumar con el segundo: `16 + 32 = 48`. Y así se repite hasta llegar al último elemento: `720 + 160 = 880`. El resultado final `880`. O sea: `((((0+16)+32)+48)+....)+160)`.

En concreto, se hace una suma de la lista, equivalente a `sum [16*x | x <- [1..10]]`.

En scala, una conversión literal sería algo así:

```scala
(1 to 10).map(x => 16*x).foldLeft(0)((x,y) => x+y)
```

O con *placeholders*:

```scala
(1 to 10).map(16*_).foldLeft(0)(_+_)
```